# Pyparsing - name not starting with a character

Tags: pyparsing

I am trying to use Pyparsing to identify a keyword which is not beginning with $ So for the following input:

```
$abc = 5 # is not a valid one
abc123 = 10 # is valid one
abc$ = 23 # is a valid one
```

I tried the following

```
var = Word(printables, excludeChars='$')
var.parseString('$abc')
```

But this doesn't allow any $ in var. How can I specify all printable characters other than $ in the first character position? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Abhijit

Comment: What characters *are* allowed as a leading character? *All* printables except '$'? Even '%', '*', '(', and '+'?

Comment: Hi Paul,The leading character can be anything other than $. So after playing around a bit I came up with var = Combine(NotAny(Literal('$')) + Word(prinatables)) Is there any better to specify exclusion criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method I used to define "all characters except X" before I added the excludeChars parameter to the Word class:

```
NOT_DOLLAR_SIGN = ''.join(c for c in printables if c != '$')
keyword_not_starting_with_dollar = Word(NOT_DOLLAR_SIGN, printables)
```

This should be a bit more efficient than building up with a Combine and a NotAny. But this will match almost anything, integers, words, valid identifiers, invalid identifiers, so I'm skeptical of the value of this kind of expression in your parser.